# Check if string contains an ID then addClass to all matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if any `<li>`'s has an ID which is matching any of the ID's given from the string `1001,1002,1003,` outputted by `arrayList` in the `for()` loop.

```
var wishArray = $.parseJSON($.cookie('wishlist_cookie'));

var arrayList = '';
var li = $('ul li');
var str = li.attr('id');

for (i = 0; i < wishArray['itemlist'].length; i++) { 
    arrayList += wishArray['itemlist'][i].wishlist_item_id + ",";
    console.log(arrayList);
}
```

Then addClass to ALL `<li>` where ID is equal to any of `1001,1002,1003,`

```
if (arrayList.indexOf(str) != -1) {
    if($('ul li').attr('id', idvalue)){
        $(this).addClass('found');
    }
}
```

How can I make it check all `<li>` ID's and then apply `.addClass('found')` to all `<li>` which matches the IDs outputted by `arrayList`?

Comment: Is there a question there ?

Comment: Do you want `$('#'+idvalue).addClass('found');` ?

Comment: So what is the problem in the code you have mentioned ? is it not working ?

Comment: How can I make it check all `<li>` ID's and then apply `.addClass('found')` to all `<li>` which matches the IDs outputted by `arrayList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply something like this instead?

Here we construct a jQuery CSS selector that will match every li with one of the listed id
and let jQuery do the rest.

```
var lisSelector = wishArray['itemlist'].map(function (item) {
    return 'li[id="' + item.wishlist_item_id + '"]';
}).join(',');

$(lisSelector).addClass('found');
```

*Note that if you do not care wheter the element is an `<li>` or not, you can simply generate a selector with `'#' + item.wishlist_item_id`.*

Answer (score 1):

variable li already contain id and using again in variable str, you may remove that:

```
var li = $('ul li')//.attr('id');
var str = li.attr('id');
```

Comment: didn't see that one, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is create a selector from the array.

```
$('#' + wishArray['itemlist'].join(', #') ).addClass('found');

// would create 
//$('#0001, #0002, #003').addClass('found');
```

Comment: @palx I will gladly delete if you point out same answer to me

Comment: @palx End result might be the same but I don't see how using a much simpler approach isn't valid